# Jettisonable wingspan for early long-range airplanes

Tags: wing, aviation-history, range, wing-sweep

Reading [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67697/does-using-wings-with-different-wing-loadings-work-the-same-as-a-swing-wing-wit), I was wondering if, at some point early in aviation history there may have been designs or concepts anticipating variable swept wing by "expendable wingspan wing"?

For example, a heavily loaded bomber  barely able to take off with its full wingspan, could jettison part of its wingspan once its mission is completed (having dropped bombs & burnt most of its fuel), to flee more quickly from enemy skies.

Ok this is not exactly what I had in mind in the first place, but it's similar. The [Hawker-Hillson FH.40 Hurricane experiment](https://fr.topwar.ru/174289-jeksperimentalnyj-samolet-hawker-hillson-fh40-hurricane-velikobritanija.html) is a Hurricane with one additional jettisonable upper wing, making it a biplane allowing for better take off and climb performances.

[image: hurricane biplane experiment]
([source](https://fr.topwar.ru/174289-jeksperimentalnyj-samolet-hawker-hillson-fh40-hurricane-velikobritanija.html))

Comment: Interesting concept! In reality, the lowered weight was used to climb higher, so the pursuit became harder.

Comment: So, I'm flying an aircraft peppered with holes, and who knows what other damage. Do I really want to take a chance that part of one wing will detach while part of the other doesn't?

Comment: Does the Short Mayo Composite count? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Mayo_Composite

Comment: I guess yes, nice find !

Comment: Saw a YouTube video on this the other day -- "slip-wing" was the name given to the concept, and it was successfully demonstrated in flight near the end of WWII.

Comment: Title:  expendable, or expandable?  Contractible might be the better term.  The question's body's "jettisonable" seems even better.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune expendable in the sense it is not reusable or recoverable with parachute, like say one SIVb Saturn V stage, which is in some way also jettisoned. Don't know which fits best, feel free to edit it's not my mother tongue :)

Comment: Well, the early versions of the Grumman Bearcat had breakaway wingtips to allow a lighter design-- if a certain  G-load threshold was reached, explosive bolts would sever both wingtips to reduce the total aerodynamic lift load on the structure.  Not exactly what you were asking about though--

Answer (score 14, accepted):

US supersonic bomber concepts were studied in the Fifties where the outer wing could be jettisoned. The WS-110 concept by North American shown below ([source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/WS-110_original_proposal.gif)) sported wing extensions with fuel tanks which could be jettisoned once tank fuel was depleted and could even return and land autonomously.

[image: North American WS-110A concept drawing]

As the wing planform indicates, with extensions the airplane would cruise subsonically and only accelerate to a supersonic dash with the outer wing jettisoned.

For a practical application I nominate the F-104 with tip tanks. The tanks extended the wingspan a bit and helped to reduce induced drag, but their added surface and mass increased drag overall. Also, even with tip and underwing tanks, the F-104 was not particularly suited to long-range flights.

Another version of extendable span puts the additional wing not in parallel, but in series. Both Arado (with the Ar-234) and Messerschmitt (with the Me-262) tried to extend the range of their jets by having them tow a fuel tank with its own wing ("Deichselschlepp").

[image: Ar-234C towing a winged tank]

Ar-234C towing a winged tank (picture [source](https://www.secretprojects.co.uk/threads/arado-ar-234-projects-and-variants.5631/page-2))

[This PDF](https://www.sto.nato.int/publications/STO%20Meeting%20Proceedings/RTO-MP-AVT-141/$MP-AVT-141-O1.pdf) contains a NATO paper on morphing aircraft, including a brief historical overview.

Comment: Trying to apply your work to cargo/passenger aircraft.  A 747 uses around 6000 gallons of fuel to reach cruising altitude and speed.  A detachable glider fuel tank may be able to give them over 1 hour additional flying time.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni The towed glider flies in the downwash of the airplane. This makes it very inefficient - total induced drag is as if all the mass is carried by the airplane alone. Adding structure for tank and wing adds to the total mass and friction drag.

Comment: Yes, but the 747 or C5 Galaxy may have sufficient thrust and structural integrity to do it, perhaps saving a much more expensive air-air refueling. (I'm also trying to show Virgin they might be able to put their rocket there too.)